# The optimal way to load referenced entities from other collections from C# and MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

In my Mongo database I have two collections, let's they are A and B.
Entities of type A has, for example, a list of ids of entities of type B. This list is just a list of strings, where each string is a string representation of B's Id.

I want to reflect these reference relationships in my domain classes (and data classes at the same time) more clearly, so that I have a list of Bs inside of A, and would be able to query this list with possible filtering or ordering via LINQ.

Currently this is implemented in the following way:
I have a class MongoReference with a static event named 'MongoReferenceLoadRequested'. This event has event args that contain a type of referenced item and its id, also it has a read-write property of type Object, where the actual loaded object is supposed to be written to.
The event is fired whenever somebody wants to have an access to A's instance's list of Bs.

In my Global.asax.cs I subscribe to this event and in the handler load desired entity and assign it to event args' property. This is done to decouple application configuration, where MongoDb connection string is stored, and POCO entities classes, that do not have (and should not have) access to connection string.

How do you think, is this a correct way of achieving my goals?

Comment: Personally, I find abstracting database calls in this way dangerous. It makes an operation of the order of milliseconds look like nanoseconds, it looks like a trivial operation but it can fail, iterating the instances causes additional operations, hydration depth is an annoying problem and the state of the item at any given time is unknown - when is it re-fetched? What if the collection was modified in between? I know this doesn't answer the question so I'm posting this as comment. Did you consider not exposing the references to B as pseudo-instance variables?

Comment: Actually, I want to expose such kind of references to make it clearer for developer that A has children of type B, not just a list of some string ids without knowledge what they reference to, and that Bs has parents of type A.

Answer (score 0):

Consider revisiting your document model in MongoDB. Sounds like a good candidate for having A have an array of B inside it in MongoDB.

```
// Document A:
{
  _id: ... ,
  values: [B1,B2,B3 ..]
}
```

This Impedance Mismatch is a legacy of RDBMS, and is due to implied relationships and the table-row kind of modeling and thinking.

See [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/) for examples and discussion of appropriate data modeling in some common scenarios.

Comment: There can be a lot of Bs in this case inside of A, and each B can have rather many children, so we can easily reach 4Mb limit for one document.

Comment: Limit is 16Mb, but the idea remains: Modeling your data in Mongo should match your application access pattern such that efficient single query can get your your most commonly used scenario. you might consider partial denormalization where the B record has its own collection and a summary-B is stored in the array for just the info you need from the join etc.